# Apply Class Items in Sitefinity 3.7 not appearing in webkit, works everywhere else

Tags: webkit, telerik, sitefinity, radeditor, sitefinity-3x

I am working with sitefinity 3.7. I have added some custom classes to the Apply Class drop down menu in the radeditor.

The problem is that they appear in firefox, the drop down gets populated and you can apply them to elements. However in Chrome and Safari they do not show up, in fact when viewing the source, they are not in there. As if sitefinity did not parsed it out.

One thing I noticed is that you had to add the style of the text(as it would appear in the drop down) in a file `EditorCssFile.css` with out that it would not show up in the list. The css is 100% valid and super basic.

Ex

```
.test {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
```

Where test is a class I have added to the classes collection

```
<classes>
    <class name="test" value=".test" />
</classes>
```

I have also made sure it is in the drop down toolbar as well

```
 <tools name="DropdownToolbar" dockable="false">
    ...
    <tool name="ApplyClass" />
    ...
 </tools>
```

Has anyone run into this at all? I seem to be at a lose for why it would show up in everything other than webkit.

EDIT:
I just want to point on that the css file that is used to display the items in the list does load, there is no errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. It was camel case.

I had some classes like `.headerImg` in my `EditorCssFile.css` and they seemed to be the problem, again only in webkit browsers.

Still really doesn't make much sense. But now it is fixed.